# How to serve Wowza amlst urls over https?

Tags: https

I got a web page that's using SSL. On the page there's a jwplayer that gets its stream from a Wowza server. If the visitor is running iOS a HLS stream with five different qualities will be served, otherwise a RTMP stream will be served. The RTMP stream is using a SMIL manifest to be able to offer different qualities. Both of the streams are served via http urls (http://mysite.se:1935/myWowzaApp/myStream/amlst:desktop/playlist.m3u8? and http://mysite.se/myWowzaApp/myStream/amlst:desktop/jwplayer.smil)

The problem is that the browser warns about mixed content (https and http) on the page. So, how do I do to serve the streams via https urls?

I've already installed a certificate to be able to connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine Monitor using https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382205/secure-streaming-in-wowza-media-streaming (and I did read the page in that answer when installing the certificate, but obviously I didn't really pay attention to what I was doing...)

So, the urls should be changed to:
https://mysite.se:443/myWowzaApp/myStream/amlst:desktop/playlist.m3u8 (works on desktop but not iPad or iPhone)

https://mysite.se:443/myWowzaApp/myStream/amlst:desktop/jwplayer.smil

Also had to open the firewall for port 443 on the server.